# SSL certificate requirement for Facebook Canvas App development

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ssl, ssl-certificate, facebook-apps, facebook-canvas

I have developed Facebook canvas app and for canvas App HTTPS and SSL certificate is required. I am planning to purchase SSL certificate but i don't know requirement of Facebook canvas app SSL certificate.My app may be hosted on subdomain or subdomain sub-directory. Please guide me which certificate is better for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to secure sub-domain and its sub-directories, you can get multi domain SSL certificate.

Multi domain SSL Certificate will protect domain in following scenarios:

> example.com
>
> *.example.com
>
> *.abc.example.com
>
> *.example.net
>
> *.abc.com.au

You can secure up to 100 domains with this certificate.